# Too far vs far enough

Tags: grammar, difference

The car was far,but it wasn't ( too far - far enough ) for me to see.
I said the answer is ( too far ),my teacher doesn't agree.
Which one is it and why?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer, "The car was far, but it wasn't too far for me to see," is correct. The alternative,  "The car was far, but it wasn't far enough for me to see," makes no sense: even if one were very far-sighted, saying the car *is far* , but *it isn't far enough to see* implies that person could *only* see things *at a very great distance*.